# jQuery: CLEditor not working?

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, cleditor

I'm trying to use [CL Editor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) (V1.3.0) for one of my projects, but I can't make it work.
I've done everything according to the "Getting started" section, so I've got a folder named 'test' that contains the following files:

```
jquery.cleditor.css
jquery.min.js
jquery.cleditor.min.js
test.html

images/buttons.gif
images/toolbar.gif
```

And my test.html file looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.cleditor.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cleditor.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#input").cleditor();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="input" name="input"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Still, when I open test.html, I just get to see a normal textarea. Any ideas what I could have done wrong? Any additional information needed?

Note: The [example](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/demos/fixedsize.html) works perfectly well, so it should not have anything to do with my browser settings.

Comment: any useful info in the chrome/firebug console? that looks correct. As a suggestion put your JS at the bottom of the body I know the sample shows it this way but its a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<body>
    <div class="text-area">
        <textarea class="cleditor" name="input" id="input"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
```

if does not work, verify the js libs integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have figured this already in case not your scripts and images should go in the accurate folder structure needed by cleditor ie
rootfolder\cleditor\images(all images)
rootfolder\cleditor(all scripts)\

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and getting following error in console ( chrome )

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined.

[Version 1.4.0](http://premiumsoftware.net/CLEditor/Downloads) is working fine.